# hybridauth: Invalid Scopes: read_stream

Tags: facebook, hybridauth

I keep getting this Every from Facebook when i hybridauth-2.5.1 when use this code below.

Invalid Scopes: read_stream. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

```
$config   = dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php';
require_once( "Hybrid/Auth.php" );


$hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );

// try to authenticate with Facebook
$adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate( "Facebook" );

// return Hybrid_User_Profile object intance
 $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();

 echo "Hi there! " . $user_profile->displayName;
```

Comment: just use google, that permission is gone since many years. the error message should be very clear, the permission just does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same Problem this was the solution

```
"Facebook" => array(
                "enabled" => true,
                "keys" => array("id" => "162293657470362", "secret" =>
               "109552243da7661c3a1c7bb90670c858"),
                "scope"   => "email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_hometown",
                "trustForwarded" => false

            )
```